# Setting max value in Filled contour plot in R

Tags: r, plot

My matrix has a max value of 100, how can I change the gradient box on the right to replace 500 by 100? (In the picture attached, the center of the green area should be red as it is around 100)

Here is my code:

```
x <- seq(350, 500, length=nrow(matrix))
y <- seq(200, 450, length=ncol(matrix))
filled.contour(x, y, matrix, 
               color.palette = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green",
                                          "yellow","orange","red")), 
               main = "Spectre 3D Puyricard",  
               xlab = "émission",
               ylab = "excitation")
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `max(matrix)` ? It seems you have >100 values

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, it probably includes the first column which corresponds to the row names (350,351,352...500). Before the code I sent earlier, I did this to ignore the first colum but it didnt seem to work: data = read.table("Spectre HVN4-2.txt", header=T, sep="\t", dec=".")
rownames(data) = data[,1]. Also max(matrix) returns [NA]
matrix <- as.matrix(data)

Comment: You need `data=data[,-1]` to remove the first column after setting rownames

Comment: I have another issue: my files have different max values: some are 60, other 100 and I would like to set the max value to 100 everytime I use this code so when you compare the pictures, only areas around 100 values are red (right now, when I run the code with a matrix that ranges up to 60, values around 60 are red so it is confusing when visualizing the plots side by side)

Comment: Solution in answers as I can't explain it properly here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the same gradient box for each of your plot, you should add the `zlim` argument as you need, it will cut the gradient according to the range you want. Here if you want from 0 to 100, just add `zlim = range(0:100)` :

```
x <- seq(350, 500, length=nrow(matrix))
y <- seq(200, 450, length=ncol(matrix))
filled.contour(x, y, matrix, 
               color.palette = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green",
                                          "yellow","orange","red")),
               zlim=range(0:100),
               main = "Spectre 3D Puyricard",  
               xlab = "émission",
               ylab = "excitation")
```